# Xamarin forms : Enable voice for chat within webview

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

Can anyone guide me on how to enable microphone capabilities to enable voice chat inside webview in Xamarin forms for both iOS and Android.

TIA

Comment: Pretty sure you will need to add the needed permissions to your app's manifest/plist. As far as the webview goes though, I think what happens in the webview is mostly detached from the app.

Comment: @SomeStudent I have added all the required permissions, but still its not working as expected and also have created custom web view but it creates a separate chrome instance and the controls goes to chrome which I don't want.

Comment: I think at that point w.e you are loading in the webview would have to enable voice chat as far as I am aware